# What data is typically stored on RFID cards and why?

Tags: rfid

1. I understand that all RFID cards contain a UID in their memory from manufacture, normally in sector 0. But they also have additional sectors for data storage, my question is what is some example data that would be stored on these cards?
2. Saying for example that the example data could be user access rights, I can't seem to understand why this data would be stored directly onto the card itself and not on the backend where the readers do a UID check, is it to prevent easy cloning?

In my experience from some extremely limited RFID security research is that most organisations implementing RFID cards are simply utilising the cards UID and the rest of the storage is blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> in my experience from some extremely limited RFID security research is that most organisations implementing RFID cards are simply utilising the cards UID and the rest of the storage is blank.

You are right, this is typically how RFID cards like Mifare are used in simple access control schemes.

However, there are more complex schemes where being able to store data on the card can be beneficial. It is especially important in applications where:

- The number of users is huge
- The access rights are a bit more complex than just "allowed everywhere" / "disallowed"
- You don't need to record each access in a central database (you just need to check the rights)

In this case, contacting a central backend for each access is not required, and would actually become a bottleneck. The data storage ability of the cards can be used to solve the problem much more efficiently, and you don't even need the access doors to be connected to a network anymore (which can also be beneficial in applications where network connection is not reliable enough, or not available at all).

There is one typical application where all these requirements are very important: **public transport**.

Checking rights against a central database for each traveller would be a huge problem. If you still want to track and record accesses, you can do it on a local database which make things much simpler. You can even simply record it on the card itself (another use of the card data storage ability): this way, you can easily tell your customers you're not spying on them (makes things much easier legally), but still have access to the history data if the customer is willing to provide his card.

As a practical example, here is the kind of information that are stored in Oyster cards (London public transport):

- Generic Card Data: Identification number of the card, Pay As You Go 
  (PAYG) Balance, Passenger type, type of discount, Photocard 
  identification number if applicable, Staff identification number if 
  applicable, the deposit value, and Registration flag.
- PAYG top up Data: Date, Time, Location, and value added.
- Ticket Data: Type of ticket, start and expiry date, and time 
  restriction if applicable.
- Transaction Data: Date, Time, Station number or bus route, and fare 
  charged.

(Source: https://www.whatdotheyknow.com/request/data_stored_on_oyster_cards)

Outside of public transport, you could imagine applications where some very personal data needs to be used to grant access, and you don't want this data to be stored in a database. Typical example is biometric data (e.g. fingerprint), for which there are specific legal considerations (you can't just store this anywhere you want, depending on the country).

Comment: Have you worked on the TfL system?

Comment: @HandyHowie I work in the smart card business, but not for TfL, and actually not many things related to transport. For information, I added the source where I found the info about oyster.

Comment: I saw one system that stored biometric data in the card so you had to have both fingerptint and card for access... that's less secure than it was now that mifare crypto has been cracked.

Answer (score 0):

The storage can still be useful when no backend connection is possible or feasible.

This was used in the past in Prague's OpenCard public transport cards a few years back, until they've switched to a more convenient and less 'hackable' on-line system. I'm certain many other cities used a similar system in the past.